# Expected value of the maximum minimum set

Tags: probability, expected-value, set-partition

Pick $m$ numbers in $[0,1]$, independently and uniformly at random.
It is known that the expected value of the smallest number is $1/(m+1)$ and of the largest number is $m/(m+1)$.

Now, partition the numbers into two sets, such that sum of numbers in the set with the smaller sum is as large as possible (in other words: solve the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) on the numbers).

What is the expected value of the smaller sum?

Comment: Is it helpful to prove $\lim\limits_{m\to \infty} \frac{4a_m}{m} = 1$  ? where $a_m$ is the number we want.

Comment: @Onir let $a_m$ be the expected value of the smaller sum and $b_m$ the expected value of the larger sum. Is your claim equivalent to $\lim_{m\to\infty}a_m/b_m = 1$?

Comment: I think I can prove both in a similar way.

Comment: Aren't they both immediate consequences of LLN? You can just put m/2 elements into two sets, and label them small and large appropriately.

Comment: @E-A yes ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Have you seen this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0009230.pdf ? In the intro to sec. 2. they point to some references that describe the asymptotic behaviour of the parition difference (exponentially vanishing) - I haven't read the rest of the paper fully but it seems to go into some details about deriving the actual distribution for the partition difference (difference between $a_m$ and $b_m$)

Comment: @JoshuaLin this is very useful, thanks